# VC++2010 unrecognized symbols for x64 platform; $(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64)

Tags: visual-c++

I have re-installed VStudio2010 and am experiencing same problem as in this [thread](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762015/).

The basic problem is that it is not possible to link for x64 platforms, the linker complains on not finding the kernel.lib.

As explained in the provided link, I can figure it out by manually adding the missing lib and include paths, however by looking at the values on the ConfigurationProperties->VC++Directories there is already a defined symbol $(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64) without its macro value (to be more clear, the symbol is listed in the Inherited values but never defined in the macro expansion).

Obviously this symbol was suppose to be used as an start point for the x64 platforms(I guess this is how before it worked as a charm), but for some reason it fails the be declared as a macro with the installation.

The question then is, where are all that symbols defined for the IDE? Have any of you hijacked this symbols to fix this kind of installation problem.

Comment: I've "fixed" similar problems by rerunning the Visual Studio Registration tool from the Windows SDK menu - does that help?

Comment: Am looking for it, was it the 7.0A SDK?

Comment: With that name ... I will need a bit more reference of the exe, plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix this problem, although am still not sure what is the source of it, why on the first place does the VStudio installer doesn't manage to set up it correctly?

You will need to add two registry strings with the appropriate values according to you installation (in my case C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include & Lib\x64)

```
Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A@IncludeFolder
Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A@LibFolder
```

And add this two lines to the file Microsoft.Cpp.x64.v100.props making reference to the registry keys, this solution goes for the v7.1 Sdk as well

```
<WindowsSDK_IncludePath Condition="'$(UseEnv)' != 'true'">$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A@IncludeFolder)     </WindowsSDK_IncludePath>
<WindowsSDK_IncludePath Condition="'$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)' == ''">$(WindowsSdkDir)Include</WindowsSDK_IncludePath>

<WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64 Condition="'$(UseEnv)' != 'true'">$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A@LibFolder)</WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64>
<WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64 Condition="'$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64)' == ''">$(WindowsSdkDir)Lib\x64</WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64>
```

After this changes macros will appear on the list from the LibDir and IncludeDir and the x64 compiling will work. 
It would be of great reference if someone installed VStudio2010 with the default SDK7.0A and worked, how does this file look.